# User specific data in Solr index

Tags: solr

Our solr index needs to have user specific status information for about 20 000 records. Each user (about 30 000) can have a status on each of this items. The status information is something like "started, success, failed).

Its required to filter based on status and also facet on those status.

Is using Dynamic fields (like "userStatus_1234" the way to go or is it a better id to have a multi value field and add "userStatus_1234:started" in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter. Having a large number of dynamic fields can overload your cache, as each field will have its own. It's usually better to structure it through a single field and query for a special value.

As the number of documents changes increase it might however be more suitable to have a separate index to search for (doc, status, user) and process that, but your solution will probably work just fine. As the number of fields increase (if every user has a status for a document, you're getting close to 30k entries for a single document), you'll want to evaluate the performance with a separate core.